# finplot candlestick chart does not render on launch when rendered as a widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph, candlestick-chart

I have placed finplot candlestick chart as a widget. When launched, it comes up black on first render of app. If I zoom out, it starts to show up in the maximum zoomed state. How can I launch it in a state so that all candles that are inside the chart is displayed. Following is my entire code.

```
import sys

import finplot as fplt
import pandas as pd
import pyqtgraph as pg
import requests
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


# Creating the main window
class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 - QTabWidget'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 1200
        self.height = 800
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.tab_widget = MyTabWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)

        self.show()

    # Creating tab widgets


class MyTabWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setTabPosition(QTabWidget.East)
        self.tabs.setMovable(True)

        self.tab1 = QWidget()

        self.tabs.resize(600, 400)

        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "tab1")


        self.tab1.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.tab1.label = QLabel("USDT-BTC")
        
        self.tab1.fplt_widget = pg.PlotWidget(plotItem=fplt.create_plot_widget(self.window()))

        self.tab1.btn = QPushButton("Press me")

        # pull some data
        symbol = 'USDT-BTC'
        url = 'https://bittrex.com/Api/v2.0/pub/market/GetTicks?marketName=%s&tickInterval=fiveMin' % symbol
        data = requests.get(url).json()

        # format it in pandas
        df = pd.DataFrame(data['result'])
        df = df.rename(columns={'T':'time', 'O':'open', 'C':'close', 'H':'high', 'L':'low', 'V':'volume'})
        df = df.astype({'time':'datetime64[ns]'})
        candles = df[['time','open','close','high','low']]


        fplt.candlestick_ochl(candles)

        self.tab1.layout.addWidget(self.tab1.label)
        self.tab1.layout.addWidget(self.tab1.fplt_widget)
        self.tab1.layout.addWidget(self.tab1.btn)
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1.layout)

        # Add tabs to widget
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is my app when launched:

[image]

Here it is when one scroll zoomed out

[image]

I want to see it as follows as soon as it launches

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for posting full details of your problem.

Everything is almost there. You just need to add two things:

1. In your `App.__init` add one of the following lines just before calling `self.show()`:

```py
fplt.show(qt_exec=False)
```

or just

```py
fplt.refresh()
```

Either choice will work because `fplt.refresh()` is called in either case. This autozooms your data plot, among other good things.

2. For the `refresh` call to work in either of the above choices, the window instance that you passed to `fplt.create_plot_widget` needs an `axs` attribute containing a list of your `fplt` widgets that you created. In your case, you wrap your `fplt` widget in a `pg.PlotWidget`, so the required widget reference becomes `self.tab1.fplt_widget.plotItem` (note the `.plotItem` there). Long story short: in `MyTabWidget.__init__` insert this line before adding your widget to `self.tab1.layout`:

```py
self.window().axs = [self.tab1.fplt_widget.plotItem]
```

Running your posted code with the above changes gives me the initial plot view that you desire.